# why does HTML agility pack not pick value before &nbsp;?

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

the html of the value im trying to get is:

```
<a href="item?id=22517505">26&nbsp;comments</a>
```

and i'm grabbing it via:

```
var storyComments = commentsNodes.Select(n => n.SelectSingleNode("//a[3]").InnerText).ToList();
```

but it only picks up everything after the `26&nbsp;` so the only value i'm getting back is "comments", not the number of them. not very helpful at all!

so to clarify, it says `26&nbsp;comments`, and all i want is the 26

how can i get the  number before the non line breaking space?

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/6Gksds I tried there and no problem occur

Comment: Wow now that is confusing! It will not work in visual studio! I just get comments! That being said I am scraping a web page so the html isnt being explicitly stated as above. I wonder, the 26 is being populated via the href. Could that affect it?

Comment: Update project to newest nuget bro https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack/

Comment: It could be a bug, give me the website, I test it on some versions

Comment: @Tan https://news.ycombinator.com/

Comment: I tested on both .Net Core, .Net Framework with nuget 1.11.21 all good bro, here is my code https://dotnetfiddle.net/DloWgX

Comment: Hmmm that's so bizarre, I'll check my nuget version I have a feeling that could be it? Will let you know! Thank you for your help bro!